# Two frontend and one backend in one app Yii Framework 2

Tags: web, yii2, project

I'm working with Yii Framework 2. How can I create an app with one backend and two front ends?

For example:

- Backend for Admins and Moderators (url: admin.example.com)
- Frontend app for Publishers (url: publisher.example.com)
- Frontend app for Advertisers (url: advertiser.example.com)

All apps should have a common db, models and 3 different layouts.
I found a Yii2 advanced template where are only two: frontend and backend.

Comment: One of the advanced templates has frontend, admin and API, which is similar you your situation. Look up on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build as many fronts as you need by adding them as independent [modules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-module.html). Each within a separate folder, with its own configs and own controllers. Then they may all share the same models.

You may check [Module docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html) for more details or you may also check [this example](https://www.diggin-data.de/dd-cms/blog/post/view/id/1004/name/Creating+a+REST+API+for+Yii2-basic-template) which is built for REST on top of a basic template, so you'll need different apache and app configs but it is practically the same.

Comment: Thanks. I made 2 extra modules and config all in urlManager. Everything works fine :)